# Azure SQL Database Copy within the same server

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

We've been using T-SQL to copy database within the same Azure SQL Server and Elastic Pool.
Suddenly using T-SQL has stopped working and viewing sys.dm_operation_status I can see that the status is IN_PROGRESS and percent_complete is always 0.
The new database never gets created either.  Just looks like the operation stops.

I can go to the Azure Portal and copy the database with the same name and Elastic Pool as specified in the T-SQL command.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By using T-SQL we can copy the database within the same
Azure SQL Server.

We reproduced the same in local environment and it's up and running.

Below are the T-SQL commands executed to get the expected output in `Query` window.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE Database1 
CREATE DATABASE Database1Copy AS COPY OF Database1
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_operation_status;
```

***T-SQL Queries:***

[image]

***Azure SQL databases:***
[image]